# Decline user invitation - devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I have integrated devise_invitable gem in my rails application to implement invite users functionality. It works good for users when they accept invitation. Is there a way to provide option for the users to decline the invitation (similar to accept invitation)? 
Along with the invitation email, I want to add opt out / decline link so that the application does not send further invitations to this user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with devise invitable configuration variable. You can look into [this url](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#model-configuration). This is not direct way to achieve this. By setting `resend_invitation` invitation email will sent to user only once.

You can setup this in two ways: In model itself

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :invitable, :resend_invitation => false
```

In Devise initializer :

```
config.resend_invitation = false
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But what I am expecting is that I want to give the user an option to opt-out and I want to save the status in my application.